# Cleaning with Tup

Tags: tup

How do I clean my build artifacts with Tup?

My project generates a *lot* of artifacts that I would like to have cleaned up. Tup doesn't seem to have a way to do it, and `git reset --hard HEAD`, even after a `git add -Af`, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tup does not have a clean function like *Makefile*s can define.

If you're using a Git repository, you can [git-clean](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) your repository.

```
$ git add -A
$ git reset --hard HEAD
$ git clean -dffx
```

If you're working on some changes and need to clean away all of the stuff without killing your changes, use:

```
$ git clean -Xf
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, you can keep things clean with variants.

```sh
touch default.config # An empty config file is ok
tup variant default
tup
```

Build files will go in the directory `./build-default`.

If you do the above in an active tup project, tup will remove all the in-situ build files and move them to the build directory for you.

There is nothing special about the `tup variant` command. It just provides a little automation. The following would acheive the same:

```
touch default.config
mkdir build-default
ln -s default.config build-default/tup.config
tup
```

Comment: Variants aren't widely supported (yet). Keep that in mind; they don't work with Windows.